# Finding the minimum number of terms in an alternating series to be accurate to be accurate to given value

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the following question here.

> How many terms do we need to sum for $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left( \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2} \right)$ so the error in the sum is less than $0.001$?

My attempt:

I know the alternating series estimation theorem says the following:

If $S=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^nb_n$ is the sum of an alternating series that satisfies:

i) $0\leq b_{n+1} \leq b_n$

ii) $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n =0$

then $|R_n|=|S-S_n|\leq b_{n+1}$

Cool. So the official solutions does the following:

$\sin\left( \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \right)<0.001$

$\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} < \arcsin(0.001)$

$n>30.622...$

$n\geq 31$

Why is this allowed though?

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left( \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2} \right)$ isn't in the form $S=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^nb_n$ since the Sin term is in the way. Can someone explain how this actually works? Thanks!

Comment: $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$, so $\sin((-1)^{n+1}/n^2) = (-1)^{n+1} \sin(1/n^2)$.

Comment: I tried plotting both though. I don't get the same graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robert Israel said, $\sin(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}) = (-1)^{n+1} \sin(1/n^2)$.

So the theorem applies: let $b_n = \sin(\frac{1}{n^2})$, and for $n>0$, we know that

1. $0 \leq \sin(\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}) \leq \sin(\frac{1}{n^2})$
2. $\sin(\frac{1}{n^2}) \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

To apply the theorem, you use $b_{n+1} = \sin(1/(n+1)^2)$.

Comment: I get that, but I tried plotting both of these and I don't get the same graph when I comapare both.

Comment: How so? Are you fixing n, or letting it range over $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I'm letting it range over $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: How are you graphing it? The values are definitely the same.

Comment: Like this:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28%28-1%29%5E%28x%2B1%29%2Fx%5E2%29

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28%28-1%29%5E%28x%2B1%29%2Fx%5E2%29+and+%28-1%29%5E%28x%2B1%29sin%281%2Fx%5E2%29

Comment: Hmm. So it looks like they only differ for n between -1 and 1.  If you look at the plots near the bottom, the functions equal out for greater magnitudes. This is only happening because $(-1)^x$ behaves weirdly for small $x \ll 1$, and you shouldn't have to worry about that in your problem.

Comment: Ahh yes. That makes sense since we mostly care about large values. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Future Math person Sure thing! :D